# How to create a circled Image overlapping each half in between two views in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: Image example]

As shown in above image I want my circled Image component to lie between two view components. I tried changing the position to absolute, but the circle gets disappeared after changing the position to absolute. Also I want a responsive kind of behavior for this screen so I can't just add a partitioned background image for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After positioning you image absolute you may have to give it a z-index more than that of View1 and View2, so the css for Image would look like:

```
.image{
  z-index: 1; //considering all other views aren't given any z-index
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Please note that this code assumes that Image is a sibling of View1 and View2

Comment: Can you suggest how to add image in entire view 1, actually adding this centered image in between blocks half of the space for view 1

Comment: @Parthshrivastav you mean to say that Image should cover whole View1 area?

Comment: @Parthshrivastav to acheive this place the image html code inside of view1 and position view1 to be relative and give height and width of 100% to image with border radius being 0.